# Google Cardboard view using three.js?

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, webvr, google-vr, vrvideoview

Is it possible to add a Google Cardboard view camera, as shown in the image below, to Google VR View, using Three.js? If so, how can I do it?

[image: example image]

More specifically, how can I add Three.js to the Google VR View code below?

```
function onLoad() {
    // Load VR View.
    vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        video: 'crusher-final.mp4',
        is_stereo: true,
        loop: false,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using the VRView-library as it runs within an iframe and doesn't provide any interface for you to add content to the 3d-views. However, it is fully open-source and implemented using three.js, see here for the source-code: https://github.com/googlevr/vrview

So you could use that code and add your stuff to it or implement it yourself.

The easiest way to do it is to use the [WebVR-polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webvr-polyfill) that does most of the work automatically. This will allow you to use the WebVR-API even if it is not yet supported by the browser.

Three.js has support for the WebVR-API built in, so there is not much more to do than to enable it using `renderer.vr.enabled = true` and setting the VR display to use via `navigator.getVRDisplays().then(displays => renderer.vr.setDevice(displays[0]));`.

See the [webvr-examples](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webvr) and the [WebVR-specification](https://immersive-web.github.io/webvr/spec/1.1/) for further reference.

Comment: how can we add three.js to the below code(google vr-view code) 
      function onLoad() {
        // Load VR View.
        vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
          video: 'crusher-final.mp4',
          is_stereo: true,
          loop: false,
        });

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you are referring to the existing library. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you put that code into your question instead of a comment here that would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß I've added the code from the comment to the question :)